# How can I have all my step definitions already defined in one java class using cucumber and selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I want to have a type of default library with all my step definitions already defined, but whenever I run my features test I get a NullPointerException because my feature contains less parameters than those received in my step definition class in total.
e.g. I have this feature:

```
@Feature1
Feature: Searching in page

Scenario: Expecting to filter partnerworld projects
    Given I am on "http://www.google.com"
    And I write "framework" in the "lst-ib" box
    Then I click the "btnK" input
    Then I should see "wikipedia"
```

and this step def class:

```
public class default_library extends DefaultPage {

@Given("^I am on \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_am_on(String url) throws Throwable {
    generalAction.loadUrl(url);
}

@Given("^I am on \"([^\"]*)\" path$")
public void i_am_on_path(String urlVar) {
    generalAction.loadFromUrlData(urlVar);
}

...Imagine 20 more step defs.
```

I only pass 5 values as parameters in the whole feature but the rest of the functions apparently get called anyways and I get the NullPointerException for those missing parameters. How can I have all my functions already defined but without getting an exception? it's impossible? am I missing something? I'm pretty new to this, please tell me if you need more information, thanks!

Exception:

```
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException
at features.bydefault.default_search_runner.features(default_search_runner.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:914)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)
at MainRunner.mainTest(MainRunner.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:571)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:707)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:979)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

short version sends me here:

```
return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
```

then

```
/**
 * @return returns the cucumber features as a two dimensional array of
 * {@link CucumberFeatureWrapper} objects.
 */
  public Object[][] provideFeatures() {
    try {
        List<CucumberFeature> features = getFeatures();
        List<Object[]> featuresList = new ArrayList<Object[]>(features.size());
        for (CucumberFeature feature : features) {
            featuresList.add(new Object[]{new CucumberFeatureWrapperImpl(feature)});
        }
        return featuresList.toArray(new Object[][]{});
    } catch (CucumberException e) {
        return new Object[][]{new Object[]{new CucumberExceptionWrapper(e)}};
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace. Can you point out which stepdef method is throwing the exception

Comment: WHAT ARE THE MISSING PARAMETERS?

Comment: any stepdef that has more functions than steps in the feature cause the exception.
By missing parameters i mean: 
if my feature has something like "given i am on "google"
but i have 3 functions (including the "i am on" ) and each function receives a parameter it will throw an exception because there are 2 other functions that don't get a value for their parameters.

Comment: If your methods were missing parameters you'd get an Arity mismatch. Please provide Stacktrace and the code the stacktrace points to

Comment: added stacktrace